# How to use different NumberStyles as input(parse) and output(ToString) styles?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have string which contains number is some specific formate. I have the style in another element and what I want is to convert this string to some other format string. For example:

```
myStyle As System.Globalization.NumberStyles = NumberStyles.AllowThousands
myString As String = "9,000,000"
myResult As String = ???????
```

I want `myResult` String to be in `NumberStyles.Number` style. i.e. `myResult="9000000"`.

Please note that the style can be anything not just a `AllowThousand` one... Does any one know any built-in Sub to convert between styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NumberStyles` enumeration can be used as parameter for the `Parse` and `TryParse` methods(f.e. [`Decimal.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx)). They can't be used in `ToString`.

If you want to control the way a number is converted to `String` use an appropriate `NumberFormatInfo` or format string(either [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) or [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.95).aspx)). For example:

```
Dim inputStyle As System.Globalization.NumberStyles = NumberStyles.AllowThousands
Dim outputStyle As System.Globalization.NumberStyles = NumberStyles.Number
Dim myString As String = "9,000,000"
Dim result As String
Dim dec As Decimal
If Decimal.TryParse(myString, inputStyle, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, dec) Then
    Dim format As NumberFormatInfo = DirectCast(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone(), NumberFormatInfo)
    format.NumberGroupSeparator = ""
    result = dec.ToString(format)
End If
```

Note that above works only if your current culture uses `,` as group separator(like in `"de-DE"` or `"en-UK"`).

In this case a simple `Decimal.ToString` would give the same result:

```
If Decimal.TryParse(myString, inputStyle, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, dec) Then
   result = dec.ToString()
End If
```

Comment: Hello Tim! Thank you for your response. Ths issue is that I am actually doing a parse to Decimal later in the code but before doing that I want to perform some checks such as lenght of the string. Based on the length a certain decision needs to be taken. But since the number can be in any style I was wondering if there was a generic parser for switching between styles.

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma: you have to know beforehand how the string is formatted, otherwise you don't know what it means.

Comment: What happens is that the string is coming in huge lengths sometimes and I need to check if it exceeds certain length if it does I need to set to my max value allowed. But the Decimal.TryParse actually failes on huge strings. Exceeding 29 character in length to be exact.

Comment: Tim Well I know the Style if that is what you mean. inputstyle has my style whatever it is. That is not an issue.

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma: still too vague. Why are your numbers longer than 29 characters? Is that a real number or do you have to determine if it is one? If so, why can't you use `Decimal.TryParse`, `Long.TryParse` or even [`BigInteger.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268268(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if it's a valid number?

Comment: Well the thing is I have huge code and in one place I am using DataGridView. I actually need to apply max and min limit on certain cells. It works fine when I am under 29 characters once I exceed that the cell instaed to mapping to max value converts the cell value to 0... That is from where the whole thing started. I tried to put a maxLength limit of the EditControl that is created on edit mode of a cell. But my lead thinks it is not a good approach as each time anywhere is the system if we use a grid we will have to enforce limits.

Comment: He is of the view that I should create such check in the custom controls that we have for our system since they are commonly called by all gridViews of the system. And that my friend is why I am stuck on this thing.